# StatefulWidget как правильно инициализировать виджет

Tags: flutter, dart

Как правильно инициализировать виджет? 
1 вариант, используя initState(), далее полный пример

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>  {
 Color _col;
 String _str1;
 String _str2;
 bool _b;

 //вызывается один раз при инициализации виджета
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _str1 = 'ru';
  _str2 = 'Hello World!';
  _col = Colors.pink;
  _b = false;
 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {
    if(_b) {
     _str1 = 'ru';
     _str2 = 'Hello World!';
     _col = Colors.pink;
     _b = false;
    } else {
     _b = true;
     _col = Colors.green;
     _str2 = 'Привет Мир!';
     _str1 = 'en';
    }
  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
     child: Container(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: CupertinoButton(
       onPressed: () {
        _f1();
       },
       color: Colors.black38,
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
       Radius.circular(25.0)
       ),
       child: Text(
        _str1,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
         color: Colors.white,
         fontSize: 22.0,
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     child: Container(
      width: 250.0,
      height: 150.0,
      color: _col,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
       _str2,
       style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 36.0
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }
}
```

2 вариант, используя только переменные, далее полный пример

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>  {
 Color _col = Colors.pink;
 String _str1 = 'ru';
 String _str2 = 'Hello World!';
 bool _b = false;

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {
    if(_b) {
     _str1 = 'ru';
     _str2 = 'Hello World!';
     _col = Colors.pink;
     _b = false;
    } else {
     _b = true;
     _col = Colors.green;
     _str2 = 'Привет Мир!';
     _str1 = 'en';
    }
  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
     child: Container(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: CupertinoButton(
       onPressed: () {
        _f1();
       },
       color: Colors.black38,
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
       Radius.circular(25.0)
       ),
       child: Text(
        _str1,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
         color: Colors.white,
         fontSize: 22.0,
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     child: Container(
      width: 250.0,
      height: 150.0,
      color: _col,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
       _str2,
       style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 36.0
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном примере разницы **лично я** не вижу, но и использовать так бы я не стал.

**1 вариант (InitState):** Из названия понятно что оно инициализирует состояния чего либо, следовательно для этого его и нужно использовать. Также оно вызывается один раз когда этот виджет вставляется в дерево виджетов.

**2 вариант:** Следует использовать в связке с `final` или `const`, например `const Color _col = Colors.pink;`, так как такие переменные должны быть неизменяемые (у них не должно быть состояния). Либо для объектов не связанных с состоянием (например какой либо запрос), оно будет инициализироваться при вызове `(new) MyHomePage()`.

---

Для того чтобы использовать StatelessWidget и иметь возможность обновлять данные (callback), мы можем поступить следующим образом:

1. Использовать [Stream (Rx)](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)
2. Использовать [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-readme-tab-)

Так как Stream довольно сложные для вас, будем использовать Provider:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MyState()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<MyState>(
        builder: (context, state, _) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Name App',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(),
              body: MyHomePage(state),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyState counterState;

  const MyHomePage(this.counterState, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Container(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: CupertinoButton(
              onPressed: () => counterState.f1(),
              color: Colors.black38,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
              child: Text(
                counterState.str1,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            width: 250.0,
            height: 150.0,
            color: counterState.col,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              counterState.str2,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 36.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyState with ChangeNotifier {
  // init
  Color col = Colors.pink;
  String str1 = 'ru';
  String str2 = 'Hello World!';
  bool b = false;

  // update
  void f1() {
    if (b) {
      str1 = 'ru';
      str2 = 'Hello World!';
      col = Colors.pink;
      b = false;
    } else {
      b = true;
      col = Colors.green;
      str2 = 'Привет Мир!';
      str1 = 'en';
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

---

*Вообще необходимо максимально отказаться от использования StatefulWidget, так как это сильно трудозатратный виджет для отрисовки и обновления его. А если нет возможности (например необходим `dispose()`) то не использовать `setState()`. А чтобы заменить StatefulWidget нужно использовать StatelessWidget с конструктором и каким либо callback'ом.*

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, спасибо Вам большое, но я не могу максимально отказаться, сейчас я изучаю события и все их варианты...Я обязательно поставлю галочку на ответе. Если Вам не трудно, то Вы удалите этото ответ и сделайте другой ответ с моим кодом но с "с конструктором и каким либо callback'ом". Если такое не возможно, то напишите и тогда я поставлю галочку на этом ответе. Спасибо.

Comment: @Anton зачем удалять и заново создавать если есть кнопка для редактирования?) Обновил вопрос, добавил код.